# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'search'). Don't know how to fetch queries in react-router version 6 , react 18

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigateurl

**Where am I wrong?**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      navigate(
              { 
                pathname: `/dashboard`,
              }
           );
    }
    
  }, []);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queries = new URLSearchParams(navigate.location.search);
```

**After fetching query I perform queries.get which is again undefined, why?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an url like this : `localhost:3000?param1=value1`,
You are supposed to do something like that to get the value from the url parameter:

```
  const location = useLocation()
  const [search, setSearch] = useSearchParams()
  setSearch(location.search)
  useEffect(() => {
    const value1 = search.get("param1")
    console.log(value1)
  },[search])
```

However, I would rather recommand to use the hook `useParams`, so you can get directly the param like this:

```
const { param1} = useParams();
//param1 contains the value1
```

Assuming that the route to this component would be:

```
<Route path="/:param1" element={<App />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'search'). Don't know how
> to fetch queries in react-router version 6 , react 18

The issue here is that it seems like you are assuming the `react-router-dom@6` `navigate` ***function*** is the same thing as the `react-router-dom@5` `history` ***object***.

```
const queries = new URLSearchParams(navigate.location.search);
```

`navigate.location` is undefined, so an error is thrown when attempting to access a `search` property.

You don't need to read the `search` string from a `location` object though because `react-router-dom@6` ships a `useSearchParams` hook to return the current URL's queryString `URLSearchParams` object and a special navigation function.

[useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams)

The `useSearchParams` hook is used to read and modify the query string in the URL for the current location. Like React's own [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), `useSearchParams` returns an array of two values: the current location's [search params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) and a function that may be used to update them.

Your code converted to get "queries" from `useSearchParams:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams(); // searchParams -> queries

useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    navigate("/dashboard");
  }
}, []);
```

Get queryString parameters as per usual:

```
const param = searchParams.get("param");
```